# How to truncate all table data using hibernate configuration?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How to truncate all table data using hibernate configuration?

For example `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate` will check validity of entity model in database. Now I need an option to truncate all tables during startup of an application.

Comment: Do you need this for integration testing?

Comment: I dont think there is anything in hibernate that will let you truncate tables on deployment as hibernate knows nothing about the deployment process. There is a create-drop option but that will drop and recreate your schema on each execution

Comment: As a remark: `create-drop` means to drop the tables at the end (to leave a clean database). Even `create` does drop the tables at startup.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate does only have the possibility to recreate the schema using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` or `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop`

Another option is to create an `import.sql` in the root of your classpath that contains the desired `TRUNCATE` statements. That file is executed automatically on startup (after validation). In that case you will have to keep the table names in sync with your database.

The last possible solution is to have your own "truncate implementation" at startup, for example as `Integrator`:

```
public class Truncator implements Integrator {
    public void integrate(final Configuration config, 
            final SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            final SessionFactoryServiceRegistry sessionFactoryServiceRegistry) {

        // Create session
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        try {

            // Find all involved tables
            for (final ClassMetadata metadata : sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata().values()) {
                final String tableName = ((AbstractEntityPersister) metadata).getTableName();
                if (tableName != null) {
                    session.createSQLQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE " + tableName).executeUpdate();
                }
            }

            final Map<String, CollectionMetadata> allCollectionMetadata = sessionFactory.getAllCollectionMetadata();
            for (final CollectionMetadata metadata : allCollectionMetadata.values()) {
                final String tableName = ((AbstractCollectionPersister) metadata).getTableName();
                if (tableName != null) {
                    session.createSQLQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE " + tableName).executeUpdate();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

An `Integrator` has to be declared in `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`, which just contains the full qualified class name.

If you use enhanced features (like *Envers*), you will need to find more table names - so this is more a proof of concept for simple data models.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Integrator interface is changed. I re-wrote the answer for the new interface:

```
static final class TruncatorIntegrator implements org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator {

    @Override
    public void integrate(Metadata metadata,
                          SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
                          SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            session.doWork(connection -> {
                try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;")) {
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.printf("Disabled foreign key checks%n");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.err.printf("Cannot disable foreign key checks: %s: %s%n", e, e.getCause());
                }

                metadata.collectTableMappings().forEach(table -> {
                    String tableName = table.getQuotedName();
                    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("TRUNCATE TABLE " + tableName)) {
                        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                        System.out.printf("Truncated table: %s%n", tableName);
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        System.err.printf("Couldn't truncate table %s: %s: %s%n", tableName, e, e.getCause());
                    }
                });

                try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;")) {
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.printf("Enabled foreign key checks%n");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.err.printf("Cannot enable foreign key checks: %s: %s%n", e, e.getCause());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void disintegrate(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
                             SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
BootstrapServiceRegistry bootstrapServiceRegistry = new BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder().applyIntegrator(new TruncatorIntegrator()).build();
StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder(bootstrapServiceRegistry).build();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().buildSessionFactory(registry);
```